Pattern of "made" joshi pitch accent
What is the actual accent of まで？
I have found so far indication for heiban-gata pitch-accent, on several online dictionaries. Now I have bumped into a thoroughly different pattern in S. Martin's renowned "a reference....." . In there, "made" has got an accent on the first mora "ma" and so Suzuki-kun tutor, by Ojad, does confirm.

Sorry it's a bit difficult to understand your English but to answer "what is the actual accent of まで". まで attaches low to accented words and attaches high to unaccented words then exhibits a downstep on ま.
E.g:
キョ↓ウトまで (京都まで)
トウキョウま↓で (東京まで)
ムラ↓まで (村まで)
This is just one category of accented longer particles so don't extrapolate this to all other longer particles. Like for example から operates differently.

I know that まで, being a 助詞 attaches low to accented words and high to unaccented words. But you must agree with me that no down step could occur if its intrinsic tone pattern were heiban as reported on Wiktionary and elsewhere . I appreciate your confirmation of the downstep on the mora ま。if まで were heiban like, say, から, then we could not have any downstep on the particle.E.g:
キョ↓ウトから (京都から)
トウキョウから (東京から)

まで is an accented long particle so it is not 平板. I don't know why Wiktionary and some other dictionaries list it as 平板. If you check the 新明解日本語アクセント辞典 or the NHK pitch accent dictionary, they do not say it is 平板 so Wiktionary is wrong (though I'm not sure why or where they are sourcing it since there's no source). Also if you just check native speech, forvo or youglish you can hear for yourself that it is an accented long particle.

I will check there. Thank you.
